# Multiple smooth lines in scatterplot

Tags: r, graph, bigdata, scatter-plot

I have the following on R, being used create a scatter graph for cost of education vs. level of education:

```
scatterplot(Cost~Education.Level., reg.line=FALSE, smooth=TRUE, spread=FALSE, 
+   boxplots=FALSE, span=0.5, xlab="Education Level", ylab="Cost", data=Dataset)
```

And the scatter graph is giving me a smooth line as well.

This is working from a large data set which also has many other variables such as City etc. How do I now break my smooth curve into several small curves which are colour coded for City. There are 3 different cities, so I'd like R to give one scatter graph with 3 different smooth lines on.

Comment: Can you please provide some data?

Comment: I don't really have any, I'm just playing around. It's basic with 3 discreet variables: Education Level, Cost of Education, City

Comment: If it does not have to be the `scatterplot` function I would suggest the `ggplot2` way of doing this as described here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html

Comment: How do I start using the ggplot?

Comment: There are a lot of introductions to this package online

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `groups=` argument. Here is a small example using the build-in data, mtcars:

```
car::scatterplot(mpg~carb, reg.line=FALSE, smooth=TRUE, spread=FALSE, boxplots=FALSE, 
span=0.5, xlab="Education Level", ylab="Cost", groups=mtcars$am, data=mtcars)
```

[image]